# Why does compiling Font Awesome Sass to CSS create a fonts folder in the wrong location?

Tags: sass, fonts, font-awesome, filepath

I'm compiling Font Awesome Sass files to CSS, and it's putting a `fonts` folder with all the font files at the root level of my project, which I don't want.

Specifically, I installed the free Font Awesome npm package as follows:

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

I then added the following to a `vendor.scss` file:

```
$fa-font-path: '../../../../public/fonts' !default;

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
```

This is the directory structure of the project:

```
(Project root)
|---fonts (I don't want this one.)
|---node_modules
|   |---@fortawesome
|       |---fontawesome-free
|           |---scss
|               |---_variables.scss (Contains original $fa-font-path being overridden.)
|---public
|   |---css
|   |---fonts (This is the one I want.)
|---src
    |---sass
        |---vendor.scss (Contains new $fa-font-path definition and FA Sass imports.)
```

If I change `$fa-font-path` to `'../../../public/fonts' !default;` or `'../../public/fonts' !default;` then the build process errors out and won't compile, but `'../../../../public/fonts' !default;` puts all the Font Awesome font files in a `fonts` folder at both the project root level and in the `public/fonts` folder. Why is it doing this, and more importantly, how can I stop it from creating the `fonts` folder at the root level? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I probably should have mentioned in my question is that I'm using the `laravel-mix` npm module to wrap around Webpack and bundle all my assets.

Laravel Mix returns a promise from its chained calls that allows you to call `then` on the end of it, from which I was able to write some custom code in the `then` callback to always remove the `fonts` directory at the project root level.

Specifically, my Mix file became the following:

```
 const mix = require('laravel-mix');
 const rimraf = require('rimraf');

 mix.js('src/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
    .extract(['vue'])
    .sass('src/sass/vendor.scss', 'public/css/')
    .sass('src/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/')
    .then(() => {
        rimraf.sync('fonts');
    });
```

`rimraf` is an npm module that basically allows you to run `rm -fr` on a directory. The module can be gotten here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf